# Interaction terms on R - Categorical and Continuous Exposures

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with continuous and categorical variables. For a linear regression, I type something like:

```
lm(a ~ b + c + d, data = df)
```

Where a is a continuous outcome. If I want to assess an interaction between C and D, I type something like this

```
lm(a ~ b + c*d, data = df)
```

My question is -- what do I do if D is a binary variable encoded as 0=no and 1=yes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width*Species,data=iris)` you get the effect for each class of the categorical variable! Try using `d` as a factor!

Comment: I don't understand your question "what do I do", what do you expect to be difficult or different than if it were categorical?